# Why does this computed property returns .white and .black?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm completely new to Swift and SwiftUI and I'm following the official apple tutorial (I'm specifically in this section right now: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-card-view). But, I do not understand this syntax:

```
import SwiftUI

enum Theme: String {
    case bubblegum
    case buttercup
    case indigo
    case lavender
    case magenta
    case navy
    case orange
    case oxblood
    case periwinkle
    case poppy
    case purple
    case seafoam
    case sky
    case tan
    case teal
    case yellow

    var accentColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case .bubblegum, .buttercup, .lavender, .orange, .periwinkle, .poppy, .seafoam, .sky, .tan, .teal, .yellow: return .black
        case .indigo, .magenta, .navy, .oxblood, .purple: return .white
        }
    }
    var mainColor: Color {
        Color(rawValue)
    }
}
```

Specifically the `return .white` and `return .black` code. Why are we returning `.white` and `.black`?

They look like enum cases or something but the `var accentColor` says it will return a `Color` type, so why are we not returning `Color()`? instead of just `.white` and `.black`? is this a SwiftUI specific syntax or something?

Comment: You are likely going to add the values for the different colors layer in the tutorial

Comment: They are not an enum cases, they are static properties on `Color`. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color)

Comment: You are actually returning the static properties `Color.black` and `Color.white` but because the `Color` can be inferred from the return type you only need to return the static property and not the whole `Class.staticProperty`.  This is a very common pattern in swift & especially SwiftUI.

Comment: Expanding on flanker's comment: The Swift compiler is pretty smart, and has something called "type inference". If the type of something can be inferred, you can skip it. So for a computed property of type `Color`, the compiler will assume `.black` is shorthand for `Color.black`.

Comment: @flanker, you should post your comment as an answer so others can see that it has been answered.

Comment: I probably should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copied from comments for completeness]

You are actually returning the static properties `Color.black` and `Color.white` but because the `Color` can be inferred from the return type you only need to return the static property and not the whole `Class.staticProperty`.

This is a very common pattern in Swift & especially SwiftUI.